# Header `###` doesn't work in markdown, but `#` and `##` does. Using ST3

Tags: header, sublimetext3, markdown

I'm working using sublimetext 3 to make markdown files.

the header indicator `#` makes a big header, `##` slightly smaller, but `###` or more than 2 hashes doesn't render. Do i need to install an ST3 package for markdown or something?

I'm using packages MarkdownEditing and Markdown Preview.

Comment: Are your sure its not generating an `<h3>` header, or is just that the styles for that level header and a paragraph are not different enough to be noticeable? Those are two very different things.

Comment: i'm not sure, but i tried wrapping a line in `<h3>` and it appears as "<h3>". Similarly, both `__` and `**` wrapping doesn't make lines bold!

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please edit your question and provide the Markdown input, the HTML output and what output you expect. As a reminder, screenshots are useless when debugging Markdown, we need the actual text.

Comment: I got it fixed in route to giving the input/output.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled all markdown packages with Package Control, then installed MarkdownEditor and Markdown Preview packages, quit and restarted ST3, and it seems to be working correctly.

I had a few other markdown packages installed- perhaps there were conflicts.